# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```js
    import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this)
  }

  handleLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // do some login logic here, and if successful:
    this.props.history.push(`/Home`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <input type='submit' value='Login' />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am getting Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in the console. Now how to access the push in the react-router v4.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

By default use can't use browserHistory in react router 4 as you can use in react router 3, still you can use different ways to push by withRouter or context but i will recommend
use withRouter HOC.
You should use the withRouter high order component, and wrap that to the component that will push to history. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  myFunction() {
    this.props.history.push("/HOME");
  }
  ...
}
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: when i use the above code , im getting the folowing error :You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Answer (score 6):

If you're using react router you need to wrap your component `withRouter` to have the history prop injected into your component.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

...

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Also whatever components you use this must be children of your router component at the top level.

Comment: when i use the above code , im getting the folowing error :You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Comment: This is related to my last comment. You need to make sure your parent components are wrapped in a `<Router>` component at the top level, using it outside of this scope won't work as it's this component that injects the history prop into your component.

Comment: import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
// import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import Login from './Login';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>
      <Login />
      </div>
    )
  }
}    this is my app.js, it this ok ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your component is not wrapped with router. wrap it with `withRouter`.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some login logic here, and if successful:
    this.props.history.push(`/Home`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: when i use the above code , im getting the folowing error :You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **useNavigate** if you installed v6 or more than "react-router-dom": ^6.2.1

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

 let navigate = useNavigate();


 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/users", user);
    navigate(`/`);
 };
```

Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239769/import-error-usehistory-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom) if you want know more about it and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjHT_NKR_gU) has a very useful practice to understand it. The video page is 'React Router V6 Tutorial - Routes, Redirecting, UseNavigate, UseParams...' in 'PedroTech' page on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your component `withRouter` to have the history prop so you can use push

Answer (score 0):

Here are the requirements that should make it work:

required imports for index.js:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { ConnectedRouter, connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
```

in your main App.js you need:

```
const history = createHashHistory();
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <App />
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>,
        rootEl,
    );
```

There where you want to use push:

```
import { push as RouterPush } from 'react-router-redux';
```