# import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to import useHistory from 'react-router-dom', however, I get this error: import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

I have checked other answers as well such as [Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861269/attempted-import-error-usehistory-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom) this but to no avail. My package.json looks like this

[image: package.json]

I am using useHistory as such,

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Login(){
    const history = useHistory();
    console.log(history)
}
```

However, this line works fine and does not cause import issues from react-router-dom.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? much appreciated.

Comment: Is your `Login` component's route wrapped inside `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: Yes it actually is.

Comment: why are you reassigning window.history?

Answer (score 14):

UseHistory have already been replaced with useNavigate
So try this

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Inside of your function:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home')
```

I hope this worked

Comment: They are not using v6 but v5 (according to the dependency screenshot) which should still have `useHistory`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works for me also. Seems useHistory is outdated now. Thanks for all above contributors

Comment: @emeraldsanto there is the "^" so when he typed npm install, it automatically installed the v6

Comment: @AyoubLaazazi that's not right, the `^` modifier will lock the major version (in this case 5) but allow newer minor and patch releases. See the docs here https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Comment: @emeraldsanto i learned a new thing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`useNavigate`  if you install v6 or more than `react-router-dom": ^6.2.1`

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

 let navigate = useNavigate();


 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/users", user);
    navigate(`/`);
 };
```

Comment: Not everyone is able to update to a new version, this is an unrealistic answer. According to their package.json, they are using v5 - typically this error arises from using history in the wrong scope. They need to make sure that the component is wrapped within a BrowserRouter on a component at least one level up in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your problem is that you need to confirm your use of the history hook is within the scope of a BrowserRouter - a quick fix would be to move the BrowserRouter component up a level to app.js or index.js - As long as you invoke the useHistory hook within the scope of a component that is already within the context of a BrowserRouter, you should have no issues in v5. The people who commented about v6 would still need to do this same fix, the answer is not to upgrade, although if you have the ability to upgrade, I would do so.

Suggested Fix: Render the BrowserRouter on the index.js

```
// index.js
...
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom' // <=V5 not compatible with V6

render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
...
```

Then on any component that is loaded within the  component, you can use `useHistory`

Learn more about history and where it can load - https://github.com/remix-run/history

Answer (score -1):

```
// `useHistory` has been replaced by `useNavigate` in react-router-dom v6

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

   function Invoices() {

let navigate = useNavigate();
  return

 (enter code here
    
<div>
      
<NewInvoiceForm
       
 onSubmit={async event => {
       
   let newInvoice = await createInvoice(
          
  event.target
        
  );
         
 navigate(`/invoices/${newInvoice.id}`);
      
  }}
     
 />
   
 </div>
 
 );

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not the answer - Upgrading to v6 is not always possible, especially on a large project with lots of tech debt - view my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70854927/10359059

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).